# Assign value to 2d array of struct in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I want to create the game 2048 in C, I have a few structs to achieve this:

```
typedef struct Board {
    unsigned int size;
    Cell ***cells;
} Board;

typedef struct Cell{
    unsigned int value;
} Cell;
```

The structs are given as a homework, so I cannot change them 
What I want to do now is initialize the Board and put one value into it:

```
Board* create_board(const unsigned int size){
    Cell ***cell = (Cell***)malloc(sizeof(Cell *) * size * size);
    Board *myboard = {size, cell};
    Cell c1 = {2048};
    myboard.cells[0][0] = c1; //I need help in this line
    return myboard;
}
```

I am just learning C and pointers are still a little confusing for me, especially if there are 3 * in a row. How do I go about assigning values to a triple pointer array inside a struct?
Any help is appreciated, it was very hard for me to find information online about this kind of problem.

Comment: The type argument to `sizeof` in `malloc()` should always have 1 less `*` than the type you're assigning to.

Comment: `Cell ***` is a pointer to a 3-dimensional array.

Comment: `Board *myboard = {size, cell};` is wrong. `{size, cell}` is a `Board`, not  pointer to a board.

Comment: You need to use `malloc()` to allocate the memory for `myboard`.

Comment: The way the triple pointer is explained in the assignment is that the first pointer, points to an array of pointers, the second one is a line in the 2d array and the third pointer is a position in the 2d array pointing to the struct. So it is a 2d array of pointers, which point to structs

Comment: That's true. In that case, you need to assign a pointer to `myboard.cells[0][0]`. `c1` is a `Cell`, not a `Cell*`.

Comment: Ok so I create a pointer `Cell *cellp = &c1` , how do I assign cellp to myboard.cells[0][0]?

Comment: You can't use that, because that pointer will become invalid when the function returns. Use `Cell *c1 = malloc(sizeof(Cell));`

Comment: I've now created `Cell c1 = {2048}; Cell *cellp = malloc(sizeof(Cell)); cellp = &c1;` but I am still stuck at `myboad.cells[0][0] = cellp;` unfortunately.

Comment: Get rid of `cellp = &c1`

Comment: You can't save the address of a local variable, since it becomes invalid when the function exits.

Comment: Your `cell` allocation is wrong. You need a nested loop to allocate each row of the board.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241149/discussion-between-cheapgucciclothing-and-barmar).